# How do i testfor multiples items in a hopper? (1.14.1)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a Minecraft sieve and my plan was to run a command that detects how many items are in the hopper, and use a loot table to spawn items equal to how much was in the hopper.

Ex: I put 5 dirt blocks into the hopper, and I get X cobble, X flint, X sticks, X grass, etc...

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I assume what you really want is a trading system? Then I would recommend googling that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply press F3 on your keyboard to get the information about your biome, position, and the targeted block. If you move your cursor onto the hopper, on the bottom right side of your screen you should see a line that reads:
Targeted Block
minecraft:xxx(block your cursor is on)

If you are targeting a complex block with multiple parameters(that is, a block with different stages/functions, i.e. wheat growing, which displays different ages) another line should pop up underneath which displays alternate parameters. In the case of a hopper, it should display the contents of that hopper.
*Note: This is concerning Minecraft Java Edition, release 1.13. This may not be standard between different versions.